# How to save/backup amazon instance local

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to lower the cost paying to Amazon.
There are stopped instances that I want to backup and save on my local server, on-prem.

After creating an image from the instance, is there any way I can copy AMI to my local server and remove it from Amazon. So in a day, I will need back, it can transfer back from my local server to Amazon to use it again?

The instance first created on Amazon.
I rather a way to save instance on-premise as a file and not as a virtual server. 
The main issue is: How can I transfer and save the image of an instance, that created on Amazon, as a file to the local server and how I can return it back to be in  Amazon, in case I need to build the instance again.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can use some backup software (duplicati, cloudberry, or anything else):

1. Install backup software to your EC2
2. Make an image backup to S3 cloud storage
3. Install backup software to your physical machine
4. Restore image from S3 cloud storage to physical machine or your local storage to keep this backup locally.

And the last, but not least thing:
 Good luck!)))

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the [VM Import/Export Tool for that](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html). Read the docs to make sure you know how to upload again.

As to the cost, I am not sure how Amazon configures the cost, that is something you have to check out from your account. Once you create the image it is on your account. Even after you download it, not sure when AWS charges you or not.

Comment: "You can't export an instance from Amazon EC2 unless you previously imported it into Amazon EC2 from another virtualization environment." - the same doc

Comment: I create the instance in Amazone, I did not import it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image file from your current drive but it will be quite expensive:

- create another instance
- attach your volume there as the second drive
- use something like `dd if=/dev/xvd0 of=drive.img ...` to copy volume to a file
- `rsync` / ftp / etc  the file to your local drive.

You will be billed for the second instance and for the transfer. When you want to restore the machine - you'll be billed too.

Have you checked [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/s/dm/optimization/server-side-test/free-tier/free_np/)? You have a year of free access to AWS for small instances and volumes.

Comment: Remember that there is no charge for data transferred in... only out.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool to get what you want. Take eg Cloudberry and create an image  and store it at Amazon and then restore and things are done. This is the best option for you. No other ways.